# Google Apps Script Getting values from sheet A (H30:I30) and pushing data to Sheet B (A6:B)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Similar to the title i would need to do this 9 times with different columns and rows so it would be for exmaple
sheet A (H30:I30) and pushing data to Sheet B A6:B (always add the data last row with no data of A6:B)
sheet A (J30:K30) and pushing data to Sheet B D6:E (always add the data last row with no data of D6:E)
sheet A (L30:M30) and pushing data to Sheet B G6:H (always add the data last row with no data of G6:H)
...
My issue is that the data is getting pushed to sheet B, not all of them will have data for that day. I would need to have it where for example
A6:B May push data only Monday in 5 days (without blank spaces)
D6:E May push data 3 out of the 5 days (without blank spaces)
G6:H May push data on Monday and Thursday in 5 days (without blank spaces)

```
function TaskHours() {

 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("homePage");
 var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("data");

 var taskOne = formSS.getRange('H30').getValue();
 var taskOneHours = formSS.getRange('I30').getValue();

 dataArray = [];
 dataArray.push([taskOne,taskOneHours]);
 datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2).setValues(dataArray);
}
```

*This does add the values to sheet B and to the last row with no data of A6:B however for example if column D14:E14 had data and I run the TaskHours function the next data would be pushed to A15:B15 instead of going to the next row with no data on A6:B.*

Answer (score 0):

I think [getNextDataCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction)) fits exactly what you need!

For example,

```
sheet.getRange("A6").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)
```

will (basically) return the cell immediately above the first blank cell in column A.

Then you can just get its row, add 1, and you've got the number of the first blank row in column A.